# How to insert tsrange using perl

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbi

Using DBD::Pg im attempting to make an insert statement with binded variables which one of them is a tsrange. I keep getting syntax errors can some one please explain the proper way to do this?

from perl script :

```
$sth->{'insert'}->execute($hashRef->{'<NUMBER>'}
                                    , $hashRef->{'<FIRSTNAME>'}
                                    , $hashRef->{'<LASTNAME>'}
                                    , $hashRef->{'<DATEIN>'} . ' ' .       $hashRef->{'<TIMEIN>'}
                                    , $hashRef->{'<DATEOUT>'} . ' ' .  $hashRef->{'<TIMEOUT>'}
                                    , $hashRef->{'<JOBCODE>'} 
                                    , $hashRef->{'<JOBCODEDESC>'} 
                                    , $hashRef->{'<COSTCODELEVEL1>'} 
                                    , $hashRef->{'<COSTCODELEVEL2>'} 
                                    , $hashRef->{'<COSTCODELEVEL3>'} 
                                    , $hashRef->{'<DEPARTMENT>'} 
            )or die $DBI::errstr;
    enter code here
```

from config file:

```
sql:
    insert: |-
        insert into etl.timeclock_plus values (
           ? 
         , ? 
         , ?  
         , [ ? , ? ] 
         , ? 
         , ? 
         , ? 
         , ? 
         , ?
         , ? 
        )   
The error : 
syntax error at or near "$4"
```

Comment: Seems rather unlikely that the error message you show would be generated by that code.

Comment: Uncaught exception from user code:
        DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$4"
        LINE 5:  , '[' $4 ',' $5 ']'
                       ^ at TimeClock.pl line 161.

Comment: Well, that whole `[ ? , ? ]` section doesn't look like valid SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
[ $1, $2 ]
```

which is invalid SQL, use a range constructor function:

```
tstzrange($1, $2, '[)')
```

There is also `tsrange` and `daterange` if you need those data types.